# setTimeout window.location keeps on doing over and over

Tags: settimeout, window.location, autoplay

I'm creating mobile page that has video player div in it.
And I'm trying to make it autoplay when someone visits the page.
So I tried this with settimeout function

My code is

javascript

```
setTimeout(function(){
                window.location = $('#play').attr('href');
            }, 2000);
```

html

```
<a id="play" href="<?=$data['video']?>">
```

I'm trying to play a video after 2sec when page is loaded.
but when I close the video and come back to the previous page, it loads the video again..
This keeps on going forever...

Is there any way to stop this?

And is there any other better way to autoplay the video other than the method I used?

The video is page. But there is nothing but a video. And when I click the link it gets large and plays by the player in the mobile device.

Comment: Why are you setting `window.location` in order to play a video? This does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

When you set window.location it takes you to the page with the video, then when you go back it starts the setTimeout again. The only way to make it work is to go at it from another route. If you need to use the href of the a tag then I would put the video in an iframe and when clicking on the link, show the iframe and set the source of the iframe.

Comment: Ok! I'll try it with iframe

Comment: It doesnt seem to work with iframe on mobile... Can you show me an example?